# Retrieve last modified directory from curl output in csh

Tags: curl, csh, shell

abcd@ubuntu:~/devbase/Shell$ curl -l http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-3/

How do I parse through this output and retrieve the last modified file or directory's name using csh script (only)?

Does curl have option to list the files according to last modified ones ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a script using csh, you've already lost. ;)

But really, this isn't a csh problem.  Use the curl `-R` or `--remote-time` option, which will attempt to set the local file to have the same timestamp as the remote file.  Then you just use `ls -1rt | tail` or find or whatever floats your boat, using local Unix timestamps.  This assumes that the remote side provides a last-modified header, which often isn't the case.  But if that header isn't provided, then there is no solution which will work without changing the remote web server.

If you only want to get the newest file, though, you probably want to use the -I option, get the headers for each file, and compare the last-modified header value.  You could theoretically have your shell script make a new, empty temporary directory, and then for each file checked, touch a file with the same name as the remote file and use the last-modified header's value for the timestamp.  Then to find the last one, use your favorite filesystem date comparison code again.  Or echo the path into each file and create the file using the date stamp in a way that will sort easily, only "actually" fetching the last sorted filename; either way.